# Semantic constraints and authentication

Tags: authenticated-encryption

In some cases (such as XML or JSON files), the bytes being encrypted have very specific semantic requirements, such that a random byte sequence will be rejected with very high probability.

In such circumstances, is it possible to do without an authentication tag, and reject forged messages at a subsequent stage?  This obviously requires that the cipher mode of operation meets certain requirements about non-malleability; to my knowledge XTS mode qualifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In some cases (such as XML or JSON files), the bytes being encrypted have very specific semantic requirements, such that a random byte sequence will be rejected with very high probability.

In the case of XML or JSON, I don't believe that's actually the case.

For example (example was the first JSON example I googled, simplified):

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",                
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

If the modification was, say, to 16 bytes in the string "Standard Generalized Markup Language" (or "example glossary"), changing that to a random 16 byte string (which is the appropriate modification model for XTS), with nontrivial probability all the bytes will be within the JSON string alphabet (and not `"`), and hence that change would not be detected, as the modified string would still be valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at Bi-IGE (bi-directional Infinite Garble Extension), a mode that changes all the bits (with 50 percent probability, of course) of the plaintext even if just one bit of the ciphertext changes value.

But note that you should still put in countermeasures against infinite retries by the attacker. Otherwise you may still get valid plaintext, even if just by chance.

Bi-IGE requires multiple passes and is therefore pretty slow. In general you should try and live with the overhead of an authentication tag. Bi-IGE should be available in the OpenSSL crypto library.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can probably get away with it, but you lose a key factor in secure design: provability.  If you use constructs which are designed to have provable security traits, you can use them with confidence.

As an example, I would not consider JSON itself to provide sufficient validation.  Why?  Because any string which matches the regular expression `"[^"\]*"` is admissible JSON.  This required 2 fixed characters (a quote on each end), plus any valid sequences of characters.  Depending on your character encoding, that might be 254 valid characters out of 256.   This means your total probability of a string matching this particular valid JSON pattern is `1/256^2 * (254/256)^N` where `N` is the number of characters in the string (which depends on the behavior of your encryption).  That pattern is absolutely going to come up easily in a brute force attack.

Now if you add more structure to it, the story changes.  If you not only need a valid JSON string, but a valid JSON string describing an object containing 3 fields: "position" "velocity" and "time", now it is much less likely that random characters meet those needs.  How likely?  Well, now it gets difficult.  You have to figure out how probable your particular JSON pattern is, and that's not always an easy computation.  Also, the computation is now intimately entwined with your data and your algorithm.  Tired of typing out "position" and "velocity" and decide to shorten them to "pos" and "vel"?  You just decreased the security of your system and need to go re-evaluate whether it is secure enough.  Write an algorithm that accidentally accepts not only an object with exactly 3 fields, but any object which contains *at least* those 3 fields?  Now you need to go re-evaluate your security, to see whether you have admitted too many fraudulent messages.

It's far more advisable to separate out the security concerns into structures which are designed to provide rapid provable security guarantees than to weave those all the way through your data.  Or at least it's far more advisable for most applications.  Take a look at your threat model, and maybe the more risky approach makes sense for you.  There's myriad examples in biology of security being woven into how animals are built and act rather than isolating them, but evolution tends to favor designs quite differently from those favored by modern security.